# How to generate multi-level associative array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, stripe-payments

I need to pass in an array of line items to generate an invoice using Stripe.  The end result should look something like this:  Notice the line_items part.

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [['quantity' => 1,
                    'price_data' => ['currency' => 'CAD',
                                     'unit_amount' => 750,
                                     'product_data' => ['name' => 'Name goes here',
                                                        'description' => 'Description goes here']]],
                    ['quantity' => 1,
                     'price_data' => ['currency' => 'CAD',
                                      'unit_amount' => 450,
                                      'product_data' => ['name' => 'Name goes here',
                                                         'description' => 'Description goes here']]]
                  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/success.htm',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/cancel.htm',
]);
```

In this example there are two line items, but there could be any number of items.  The issue is of course that I need to generate this array of line items before passing it in and these line items are coming out of the DB.

So ideally, I could generate that line_items array in a variable and just pass in that variable instead; like so:

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [$lineitems],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/success.htm',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/cancel.htm',
]);
```

So far however, no luck.  I can generate a string in a loop like so:

```
foreach($rows as $row){
   $linedescription = $row["itemname"];
   $lineamount = $row["amount"];
   $linecomment = $row["comment"];

   $lineamount = $lineamount * 100;

   if($index > 0){
     $lineitems .= ",";
   }

   $lineitems = "['quantity' => 1,'price_data' => ['currency' => '".$currencycode."','unit_amount' => ".$lineamount.", 'product_data' => ['name' => '".$linecomment."','description' => '".$linedescription."']]]";

   $index ++;
}
```

Which gives me exactly this:

```
"[['quantity' => 1,
                    'price_data' => ['currency' => 'CAD',
                                     'unit_amount' => 750,
                                     'product_data' => ['name' => 'Name goes here',
                                                        'description' => 'Description goes here']]],
                    ['quantity' => 1,
                     'price_data' => ['currency' => 'CAD',
                                      'unit_amount' => 450,
                                      'product_data' => ['name' => 'Name goes here',
                                                         'description' => 'Description goes here']]]
              ]"
```

Problem is, it's a string and I need it to be an array.  I've tried json_decode and I've tried generating an array in the loop instead of a string but I can't seem to end up with what I need.  Surely there's an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an array in the same way as you are building your string. I've split each dimension into a separate line of code for readability but you could combine them into one line if you desired:

```
$lineitems = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $product_data = array('name' => $row["comment"],
                          'description' => $row["itemname"]
                          );
    $price_data = array('currency' => $currencycode,
                        'unit_amount' => $row["amount"],
                        'product_data' => $product_data
                        );
    $lineitem = array('quantity' => 1,
                      'price_data' => $price_data
                      );
    $lineitems[] = $lineitem;
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
'line_items' => $lineitems,
```

in your call to `\Stripe\Checkout\Session::create`.

Note that without sample data for testing it's hard to be certain, but this code should work as expected. Also note that it would seem from the names that perhaps the `name` entry should be `$row['itemname']` and the `description` should be `$row['comment']`?

Comment: Thank you.  That does generate the array as expected, unfortunately my stripe call is still not accepting it.  :/  I tried adding single quotes to the product_data, etc but that didn't work, and I tried wrapping $lineitems in a json_encode but that didn't work either.  I notice when I echo the json_encode version the format includes squiggly brackets instead of square. I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Comment: Does the call you show at the beginning of the question work? Because this code should produce exactly the same input data as long as you use `'line_items' => $lineitems,`, not `'line_items' => [$lineitems],`

Comment: Yes, the call at the beginning does work.  And I tried passing in the array generated by your example, just as you suggest using only 'line_items' => $lineitems, but that does not work.  I get a 500 error when loading the page. (by the way, how do you highlight code in your comment?)

Comment: Never mind.  Turns out, I'm an idiot.  I coulda swore it did not work earlier.  :/

Comment: @Vincent To highlight as code in a comment, insert between backticks. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting